# Infinite groups with no infinite abelian quotients

Tags: group-theory

Can one please give me an example of an infinite finitely generated group without infinite abelian quotient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly the simplest example is the infinite dihedral group, which can be realized as the set of maps on $\mathbb{Z}$
$$
G = \{ x \mapsto \varepsilon x + \lambda : \varepsilon \in \{1, -1 \}, \lambda \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
$$

Consider $a : x \mapsto x + 1$ and $b : x \mapsto -x$. Then $[a, b] = a^{-1} b^{-1} a b : x \mapsto x - 2$, so that $[a, b] = a^{-2}$, the derived subgroup is $G' = \langle a^2 \rangle$, and $G/G'$ is a [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Answer (score 4):

Consider any infinite $G = \langle g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_t \rangle$ such that each $g_i$ has finite order.